# mysql connection driver to dockerize the cakephp 1.3 application

Tags: mysql-connector, cakephp-1.3

**.env** file

```
export MYSQL_URL='mysql'
export MYSQL_USERNAME='root'
export MYSQL_PASSWORD=''
```

**database.php** file

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public function __construct(){  
 $this->default['host'] = getenv('MYSQL_URL');  
 $this->default['login'] = getenv('MYSQL_USERNAME');  
 $this->default['password'] = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');
}

var $default = array(
 'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',  // incompatible driver for cakephp 1.3
 'persistent' => false,
 'host' => '',
 'login' => '',
 'password' => '',
 'database' => 'RP',
 'prefix' => '',
 //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
}
```

Unable to import DataSource class due to incompatible driver for the cake version used

[image]

please suggest a compatible mysql connection driver for cakephp 1.3 on docker

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 1.3 didn't use namespaces. I think you just want `'driver' => 'mysql'`.

Comment: I had tried it already,

then it is showing, 


Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /var/www/html/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 613

Comment: `mysql_query` was removed in PHP 7. If you want to use Cake 1.3, you'll need to be using PHP no later than 5.6.